# Contact form using MailForM in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, contact-form, mail-form

I am new to web development and I am presently learning rails. I made a simple contact form and I am able to get the email to deliver via the console as indicated on MailForm page

> c = StaticPage.new(:name => 'José', :email => 'jose@email.com', :message => >'Cool!')
>   c.deliver

When I do same via my form though I keep getting the "Cannot send message" flash. Here are my codes

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

get 'password_resets/new'

get 'password_resets/edit'

root 'static_pages#home'

get '/login', to: 'sessions#new'

post '/login', to: 'sessions#create'

delete '/logout', to: 'sessions#destroy'

get '/signup', to: "users#new"

post '/signup', to: "users#create"

get '/help', to: "static_pages#help"

get '/about', to: "static_pages#about"

get '/contact', to: "static_pages#contact"

resources :users  #connects to the show action in users_controller
resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
resources :password_resets, only: [:new, :edit, :create, :update]
resources :static_pages, only: [:index, :new, :create]
end
```

static_pages_controller.rb

```
 class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @contact = StaticPage.new
  end

  def index
    @contact = StaticPage.new(params[:home])
  end

  def create
    @contact = StaticPage.new(params[:home])
  # @contact.deliver if @contact.valid?

  @contact.request = request
  respond_to do |format|
  if @contact.deliver
      # re-initialize Home object for cleared form
      @contact = StaticPage.new
      format.html { render 'index'}
      format.js   { flash.now[:success] = @message = "Thanks for contacting us!" }
    else
    format.html { render 'index' }
    format.js   { flash.now[:error] = @message = "Cannot send message." }
    end
  end
end

  def help
  end

  def about
  end

# def contact
# end

end
```

static_page.rb

```
class StaticPage < MailForm::Base
  attribute :name,      :validate => true
  attribute :email,     :validate => /\A([\w\.%\+\-]+)@([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,})\z/i

attribute :message
attribute :nickname,  :captcha  => true

# Declare the e-mail headers. It accepts anything the mail method
# in ActionMailer accepts.
 def headers
  {
    :subject => "Contact You",
    :to => "mymail@gmail.com",
    :from => %("#{name}" <#{email}>)
  }
  end
end
```

_contact_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for :contact, url: static_pages_path, remote: true do |f| %>
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= f.label :name %></br>
    <%= f.text_field  :name, required: true, class: "contact-form-text-area" %></br>

    <%= f.label :email %></br>
    <%= f.text_field :email, required: true, class: "contact-form-text-area" %></br>


  <%= f.label :message %></br>
  <%= f.text_area :message, rows: 8, cols: 40, required: true, class: "contact-form-text-area",
                    placeholder: "Send to Page."%></br>

  <div class= "hidden">
    <%= f.label :nickname %>
    <%= f.text_field :nickname, :hint => 'Leave this field blank!' %>
  </div>

  <%= f.submit 'Send Message', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
</div>
<% end %>
<div class="col-md-6" id="flash-message">
  <%= render 'flash' %>
</div>
```

development.rb

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in 
  config/application.rb.

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  Show full error reports.
  config.consider_all_requests_local = true

  # Enable/disable caching. By default caching is disabled.
  if Rails.root.join('tmp/caching-dev.txt').exist?
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

    config.cache_store = :memory_store
    config.public_file_server.headers = {
      'Cache-Control' => 'public, max-age=172800'
    }
  else
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

    config.cache_store = :null_store
  end

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  host = 'rails-tutorial-myid.c9users.io'
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: host, protocol: 'https' }
  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

  #Settings to deliver form email to gmail
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
    port:                      587,
    domain:                 'gmail.com',
    user_name:           ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"],
    password:              ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"],
    authentication:      'plain',
    enable_starttls_auto: true,
    openssl_verify_mode: 'none'}

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations.
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.debug = true

  # Suppress logger output for asset requests.
  config.assets.quiet = true

  # Raises error for missing translations
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true

  # Use an evented file watcher to asynchronously detect changes in source code,
  # routes, locales, etc. This feature depends on the listen gem.
  config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::EventedFileUpdateChecker

  end
```

Log

```
Started POST "/static_pages" for 10.240.1.50 at 2018-01-18 10:35:20 +0000
Cannot render console from 10.240.1.50! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1,         127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by StaticPagesController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "contact"=>{"name"=>"Jane", "email"=>"jane@gmail.com", "message"=>"wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww", "nickname"=>""}, "commit"=>"Send Message"}
  Rendering static_pages/create.js.erb
  Rendered static_pages/_flash.html.erb (0.5ms)
  Rendered static_pages/_contact_form.html.erb (5.1ms)
  Rendered static_pages/_flash.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered static_pages/create.js.erb (8.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 23ms (Views: 11.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

My gmail id and password are saved in another file. I also tried just using plain values in the config. At this point the one from the console got delivered.

I have gone through all related posts on this platform and a lot on google but still can't figure out why it won't deliver. My guess is that it's something to do with my controller. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Have you configured the mailer to accept + send the email? You need to go to RAILS_ROO/config/environment/, and choose `development.rb`. In there you need to set your mailer to do something like this: `ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :sendmail`

Comment: Thanks for the comment mutantkeyboard, I added that but still won't work. I am adding my development.rb config code.

Comment: Have a look in your logs and tell us what is coming through to `params` when you post your form... i suspect you're retrieving it using the wrong name/structure.

Comment: I am adding the log when I submit the form, Taryn.